# Bind ContextMenuItem Property to a DataGrid or an other Element Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I trying to bind ContextMenuItem property to a DataGrid Property as flow:

```
<DataGrid Name="DG_Data" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL3"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="COL4"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button Name="BTN_OpenContext" Content="CLICK TO OPEN">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Name="CM_ContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding ElementName=DG_Data,Path=Columns.Count,FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

I have tried also using the different way with RelativeSource

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=2,AncestorType=FrameworkElement}, FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" />
```

I have just be able to bind to the parent (the ContextMenu).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` can't bind to the `DataGrid` using `ElementName`, but it can't bind to a property of the parent `ContextMenu`'s `PlacementTarget` (which is the `Button`).

So you could bind the `Button`'s `Tag` property to the `DataGrid`, and then bind to the `Tag` property from the `MenuItem`:

```
<Button Name="BTN_OpenContext" Content="CLICK TO OPEN"
        Tag="{Binding ElementName=DG_Data}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="CM_ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.Columns.Count, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, FallbackValue=BindingFailed}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: You have explained that very clear, Thank you very much for your quick reply.